# Jython library for interfaces

Tags: python, interface, jython, java, objectfactory

I'm working through [this](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html) `Jython` guide to make a one-to-one `Jython` Object Factory.

The writer speaks of a `org.jython.book.interfaces` that he uses through out the tutorial.

> In order to utilize a Jython module using this technique, you must
>   either ensure that the .py module is contained within your sys.path,
>   or hard code the path to the module within your Java code. 
>   A python module that implements a Java interface to create a building object

```
from org.jython.book.interfaces import BuildingType
```

I've imported every `jython.jar` I could find, and this part of the library does not exist. In his tutorial, he creates a `building.py`, `buildingType.java`, and a `buildingFactory.java`.

Here is my code where the app hits and fails to keep running:

```
package my.irondb_datdiff;


import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.core.PyString;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;


public class DiffFactory {

  private PyObject diffClass;

  public DiffFactory() {
    PythonInterpreter pyin = new PythonInterpreter();

    pyin.exec("from make_diff_from_irons import make_diff_from_irons");
    diffClass = pyin.get("make_diff_from_irons");        

}

  public make_Diff run(String export, String source, String target) {

    PyObject diffObject = diffClass.__call__(
        new PyString(export),
        new PyString(source),
        new PyString(target));

    return (make_Diff)diffObject.__tojava__(make_Diff.class);

}

}
```

And here is the line it hits that it files on after doing "run":

```
from my.irondb_datdiff import make_Diff
```

I've made my versions of these, but I get the error that my module does not exist. I'm sure this is because I'm not importing the interface because I can't find the right module in the library.

Any thoughts?

(Also I realize a another poster had a similar question about this exact step in the tutorial, but this question is different and the other posters answer didn't answer my question. So please don't mark as duplicate.)

Comment: Please include your code and the locations of the source files.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by source files, but my NetBeans8 project folder is separate from my jython .jar files. In NetBeans though, I've imported the .jar files into the Library's folder.

All of the .java and .py scripts are in the same package in the same project.

Comment: `org.jython.book.interfaces` is not going to be in a standard Jython library, if that's what you mean, as you can see by the "book" in there.

Comment: Hmm, thank you, it's good to know I was bringing the libraries in to NetBeans correctly. Well I guess now the trick is tracking that library down. So far Google searches lead only to the original authors blog about that library...